# convert (sed or awk, or anything) file containing the following:

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I am looking for a way to convert with a one line linux command (sed or awk, or anything) the following file (example1.txt);

```
1.2.3.4:21
172.16.1.2:80
192.168.5.4:443
192.168.10.1:7007
```

into a format like this:

```
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Welcome to askubuntu, could you show us what you tried so that we can help you with that?

Comment: It puzzles me how this type of questions are so well received here. Imagine asking on any of the other Stack Exchanges _"Please write me a program that does X"_ without any further information.

Answer (score 5):

AWK you can do using variables like below.

```
awk -F ':' -v q='"' '{print q $1 q " "  q $2 q}' example1.txt
```

`-F` Defines the field separator. That is how it divides two columns into `$1` and `$2`.

`-v` Helps us to define a variable which is `q`. `q` contains the double quote.

`" "` Extra space here gives space between prints.

1. Printing the first field:

   ```
   $ awk -F ':' '{print  $1}' example1.txt
   1.2.3.4
   172.16.1.2
   192.168.5.4
   192.168.10.1
   ```
2. Printing the second column

   ```
   $ awk -F ':' '{print  $1  $2}' example1.txt
   1.2.3.421
   172.16.1.280
   192.168.5.4443
   192.168.10.17007
   ```
3. Adding the space in between.

   ```
   $ awk -F ':' '{print  $1  " " $2}' example1.txt
   1.2.3.4 21
   172.16.1.2 80
   192.168.5.4 443
   192.168.10.1 7007
   ```
4. Adding double-quotes.

   ```
   $ awk -F ':' -v q='"' '{print q $1 q " "  q $2 q}' example1.txt
   "1.2.3.4" "21"
   "172.16.1.2" "80"
   "192.168.5.4" "443"
   "192.168.10.1" "7007"
   ```

Above command will only print it. If you want to save it to a file you can run below command.

```
$ awk -F ':' -v q='"' '{print q $1 q " "  q $2 q}' example1.txt > example2.txt
$ cat example2.txt
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Moreover, below command can give you the same result too.

```
$ awk -F':' '{print "\""$1"\""" ""\""$2"\""}' example1.txt
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Answer (score 3):

There's no need to use multiple sed command when they all can be concatenated into one:

```
sed 's/^/"/; s/:/" "/; s/$/"/' input.txt
```

Using awk:

```
awk '{sub("^","\"");sub(":","\" \"");sub("$","\"");print}' input.txt
```

Answer (score 3):

### Using Sed

```bsh
sed 's/\(.*\):\(.*\)/"\1" "\2"/'
```

### Using Bash

```bsh
while IFS=: read addr port; do echo \"$addr\" \"$port\"; done
```

or even

```bsh
while read line; do echo \"${line/:/'" "'}\"; done
```

Comment: I like the `sed` approach. I was going to look for it.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this simple command:

```
cat input-file | sed 's/:/" "/' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/'
```

Remember to replace `input-file` with your real file name.

If you need to save the output to another file then add the output redirection, like this:

```
cat input-file | sed 's/:/" "/' | sed 's/^/"/' | sed 's/$/"/' > output-file
```

as before, remember to replace `output-file` with your preferred output file name.

...and that's all! ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Miller (https://github.com/johnkerl/miller) and running

```
mlr --csv --quote-all -N --ifs ":" --ofs " " cat input.csv
```

you have

```
"1.2.3.4" "21"
"172.16.1.2" "80"
"192.168.5.4" "443"
"192.168.10.1" "7007"
```

Comment: Getting an internal server error from github, which shows why 1) answers should not depend on third party websites, and 2) it's better to use standard unix tools for this kind of simple text processing

Answer (score 0):

This isn't a single command line, but you can do this in vim: record a macro to alter the line and move down, the repeat as many times as lines (I'm assuming 1000 lines)

```
qqI"<Esc>f:s"<Space>"<Esc>A"<Esc>jq1000@q
```